# How to find the current time of any city in the world with PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

For example, I would be able to type a function like so:

```
echo findtimeinworld('<some way to format Sydney, Australia>'); // The current time in Sydney, Australia in a timestamp
```

How would such a function be possible?

Also, please note I'm working on a hosted server here, so the server time may be anything.

Bonus votes for the smallest possible function.

Comment: You're going to need a database containing time zone information for every city that is to be queried, and then make a time zone adjustment to your current server time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Talking about databases, could it be small enough to be stored in an array?

Comment: [This one](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) is about 200 kilobytes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh, cool! Could you summarise it in an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need a database containing time zone information for every city that is to be queried, and then make a time zone adjustment to your current server time.

There is a Time Zone database [located here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  It looks like it comes with some C code to dump the time zone information to a file that, hopefully, is importable to a database table.  Once you have that, you should be able to get a time zone adjustment for any city in the world, at any time of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Check this webservice this is helpful to achieve timezone of the city along with local time.

http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone

here's it's example (for New York).

http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/40.71417/-74.00639

Note that there are some usage restrictions:

> 1. You must not make more than one request per second to these webservices.
> 2. You must cache results if you believe that you will need to make another identical request within any 24-hour period.
> 3. You must delete any cached data when you no longer need it and in any case after 14 days.

Comment: well, in that case, is there a function for finding the latitude and longitude of a city? I'm not searching them up one by one.

Comment: @think123 you can use google api for that... check this url http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new%20york%20usa&sensor=false

Comment: @NiravRanpara Google Geocoding API check this url https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: This answer seems incorrect though. I searched up where I live, and it isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
date_default_timezone_get();
```

Try this.

Comment: So you're saying temporarily change the time zone of the server, grab the time, and then change the time zone back?  I'm not sure that's the best idea; it's going to break any other software that depends on accurate time and reads the time while the time zone is wrong.

Comment: Do you really expect that every small village is known by php?

Answer (score 0):

The date and time functions works according to server, so you have to manually set timezone before any date and time functions are called.
And since you are in need of a function that will show the time depending upon the argument passed, the effecient way will be settign the timezone depending upon the argument passed.
For that you will require an database or probably an array of timezones (array will be too big with hundreds of indexes) and match them accordingly.

Below is an short pseudo code

```
echo findtimeinworld('COUNTRY/CITY'); //findtimeinworld('Australia/Melbourne');

    function findtimeinworld($suppliedTZ){

        //Match $suppliedTZ with timezone database for complete match
        //if match found
        date_default_timezone_set('returned timezone'); 
        //else if match not found
        //match for first part ex Australia and limit the result to 1
        //if match found
        date_default_timezone_set('first returned timezone'); 
        //else if match not found
        date_default_timezone_set('your default timezone');

        //put date and time functions here
    }
```